# Optimal hash load factor for optimizing memory usage

Tags: redis

I'm having a hard time thinking about persistence around hashtable memory optimizations.

From what I understand, the way hashes are stored can be fine-tuned to allow for efficient memory usage using the hash-max-zipmap-entries and hash-max-zipmap-value configs. Below the threshold, values are basically "serialized" and scanned linearly. Above the threshold, they get converted into real hash tables.

So with this in mind, what we really want is to tune those two configurations such that we can trade off a little space for a little more CPU time such that we can still maintain O(1) access times without incurring noticeably high CPU usage.

Is there a rule of thumb for the number of "buckets" to choose if growth is unbounded? Is there an optimum load factor that we should be shooting for to take advantage of the memory optimizations? If the load factor becomes too high, would it be advisable to create more buckets and manually rehash all the hashtable entries to maintain an optimal load factor?

Any insight/advice would be appreciated!